# Embedded SoundCloud player widget displays suggestions after file is played

Tags: soundcloud

I don't want to have the soundcloud widget display suggestions after an embedded sound has ended. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that at the moment.

Comment: It does provide an answer, but a little more explanation or reference to documentation would be helpful. Can you show that is it not possible?